# How to use `MutationObserver` to observe properties of an `HTMLElement` rather than attributes

Tags: javascript, html

With [`MutationObserver.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe), I can listen to changes in a certain attribute. For example, if I have a Div, and the attribute `value` changes, then the assigned callback would be called. However, if the property (of the same name) is changed, it would not be called:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

divNode = document.getElementById('my-id');

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(divNode, {attributes: true});

// ...

// This will trigger `callback` to be called
divNode.setAttribute('value', 'something new')

// This will do nothing, since value is a property, not attribute
divNode.value = 'something new'
```

I believe (but haven't tested) this is an issue since `value` is not a "known" attribute of `<div>`, thus Javascript will not automatically update the associated attribute when the property is updated.

What's the best way to listen to `divNode.value` specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a MutationObserver can do this. A different approach would be to overwrite the `.value` getter/setter:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const { get, set } = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'value');
Object.defineProperty(input, 'value', {
  get() {
    console.log('got');
    return get.call(this);
  },
  set(newVal) {
    console.log('set');
    return set.call(this, newVal);
  }
});

input.value = 'some value';
```

```html
<input>
```

But this is extremely weird. I would hope never to see this in serious code, unless you're in an odd situation where you need to observe changes that you have no control over otherwise (such as when running someone else's script).

Comment: This solution requires doing it for each `input` element you want to watch. Could you also do it by patching the property in the HTMLInputElement prototype?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that too. Patching prototypes or objects you don't own is occasionally prone to breaking things, probably only do it if you have to

Comment: Another possibility: Define a custom element that's a subclass of `HTMLInputElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Proxy

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

```js
function watchPropsOn(el) {
  return new Proxy(el, {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
      console.log('get', propKey);
      return el[propKey];
    },
    set(target, propKey, value, receiver) {
      console.log('set', propKey, value);
      target[propKey] = value;
    }
  });
}

let divNode  = document.getElementById('my-id');

let divProxy = watchPropsOn(divNode);
divProxy.value = 'some text';
console.log(divProxy.value);
```

```html
<input id="my-id">
```

Comment: How would this show when a user types too, or do we ALSO need to set an eventListener?