# How to properly listen for checkbox.checked when it is modified by scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

### Question

There's a checkbox: `<input type="checkbox" id="led">`. I want to be notified when a certain script try to change the value `led.checked`. Note that I have no idea what that script might be, nor can I modify it.

### My attempts

The first solution that came to my mind was `led.addEventListener("change", () => {console.log(led.checked);})`. However, this only works when the user clicks on the checkbox.

The second solution I tried:

```js
var led_val = led.checked;
Object.defineProperty(led, "checked", {
    get: () => {
        return led_val;
    },
    set: (val) => {
        led_val = val;
    }
})
```

The script seems to be working as expected, but the appearence of the checkbox won't be updated. i.e. When `led.checked = true` is executed, we're notified and `led.checked` does return `true`, but the checkbox looks as if it is not checked. Also, clicking on it won't update the value `led.checked`.

Comment: Maybe try to return `true` when you set the val, to indicate the opeartion has succeed

Comment: Solved.
MWE: https://github.com/PRO-2684/gadgets/tree/main/checkbox_patch
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68426166/16468609